# StyleCop - Suppress rule only for method name

Tags: static-analysis, stylecop, suppress-warnings

For example, My naming rule for a method is `SampleName` and for parameter it is `sampleName`. In the following code I do not have control over method name as it is public and virtual so I can't change it to `GetIds` to match my naming rule.

```
public override void GetIDs(ref string[] availableDefinitionElementIDs)
{
}
```

In order to build my program successfully I have to suppress following rule.

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCopPlus.StyleCopPlusRules", "SP0100:AdvancedNamingRules", Justification = "?")]
```

But problem here is that it also suppresses warnings for parameter list and any code within the method.

Is it possible suppress rule only for specific element of a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can not suppress message only for the method declaration line in StyleCop.

As for your particular StyleCop+ issue, you could

- add "IDs" to the "Compound words / abbreviations" StyleCop+ setting

or

- add "GetIDs" in method naming rules (as an exception)
- add "availableDefinitionElementIDs" in parameter naming rules (as an exception)